# File path versioning cache bursting not working and modified date response header is coming as very old date as 1985 for my react bundle

Tags: reactjs, npm, browser-cache, last-modified, npm-package

I have a react bundle with a versioning url to burst the cache on every new change.

Example : [https://example.com/test/{version}/bundle.js](https://example.com/test/%7Bversion%7D/bundle.js)

This bundle is getting generated with the help of npm 6 which generates tarball and files inside tarball are of very old time stamp 26 Oct 1985. And server also returns the same timestamp to the browser.

My question is, how to burst the cache in this scenario, cache bursting is not happening even with version change in the bundle path.

I am looking for a solution.

My question is, how to burst the cache in this scenario, cache bursting is not happening even with version change in the bundle path.